# How to get to ALSA Bus Station Valencia from Valencia Airport?

Tags: trains, airports, buses, valencia

How do I get to ALSA Bus Station Valencia from Valencia Airport? Can I take the last metro from the Airport? And how do I buy tickets for it? I'm coming at 23:30 and need to be at ALSA Bus Station around 3:30AM.

Answer (score 1):

Some minor points of clarification:

1. It's not the Alsa bus station, it's just the general bus station.
2. Is 23:30 when your plane lands or your estimate for when you'll be through deplaning, immigration, baggage collection, etc?
3. What day? The last metro varies.

The metro's website is http://www.metrovalencia.es/ . The [timetables page](http://www.metrovalencia.es/horarios.php?page=143) shows that today the last metro leaves at 23:57 (and for what it's worth the first one was at 05:27). If the plane is scheduled to land at 23:30 then you may have to run, and you may even just miss it. The signage is fairly good, but if you're running then basically once you get through the baggage hall you head left and keep going almost until the end, and then go through the glass doors on your right and down.

If you have time to make it, the tickets can be purchased from machines in the metro station using cash or card. There are two lines from the airport, but both of them go through Túria, which is the nearest metro station to the bus station. The airport is the terminal, so you don't need to worry about getting the right direction.

If you miss the last metro then the only option is taxi. I think it will cost about 20€.

Comment: So I'm coming on the 6th July 23:30. I don't know how much Valencia airport is big, but I think it should go fast with everything because I'm flying inside EU with the cabbage bag. :) It says on this link on the 7th July last metro is 00:27?

Comment: Yes, you've got the 23:47 (maybe possible with luck, particularly if the plane arrives early) and the 00:27 (easily made). Valencia airport is quite small.

Comment: @dino23, I suddenly realised today that I'd misremembered the name of the metro stop. Now corrected to Túria.